# Laravel 'popper.js is null' when clicking on a bootstrap 4 div with class 'input-group-prepend'

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I receive the following error in the console when I click on element that's surrounded by a div with the class `input-group-prepend`:

> TypeError: popper is null app.js:50778:3

If I remove the surrounding div the click function works, but I need the div for UI reasons.

**The element**

```
...
<div class="input-group-prepend">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle"
           type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filter
   </button>
</div>
...
```

**Jquery click function**

```
...
$(".dropdown-item-container").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log($(this));
});
...
```

My guess was that I hadn't included `popper.js` correctly in `boostrap.js`.

**My `bootstrap.js` file:**

```
...
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
...
```

I tried some of the seemingly related solutions described here, but I wasn't able to get them to work: [Can't load popper.js with webpack and Laravel mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022976/cant-load-popper-js-with-webpack-and-laravel-mix).

I use:

- `Laravel` version: 6.7.0
- `Popper.js` version: ^1.16.0
- `Bootstrap` version: ^4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a strange, but easy fix. For some reason when I put the `data-toggle="dropdown"` on the surrounding `div` instead of on the `button` the dropdown works and I don't get the error.

```
...
<div class="input-group-prepend" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle"
           type="button"
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filter
    </button>
</div>
...
```

I don't know why this works and it is not how the `Bootstrap` documentation prescribes creating a dropdown, but it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `div.dropdown-menu` should be sibling to the `button[data-toggle="dropdown"]`. Maybe that's the problem.

If you don't want to change the HTML structure, you'll have to define the `reference` setting on dropdown options (e.g. `data-reference="parent"`). See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/#options